# Feeding get into pv and writing to log file not working

Tags: linux, bash, get, xargs

So I'm trying to feed the output of a file (that's retrieved using get) into a log file.

What I have is this:

```
 get whateverfile | pv > somefile.log
```

I've also tried feeding it with xargs:

```
 get | pv whateverfile > somefile.log
```

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/pv-command-examples/

pv -options input.file | command1 | pv -options > output.file

So in your case, something like:

pv input.file | get | pv > somefile.log

**NOTE**: Code is untested.